# Is GLKMatrix4Translate correct?

Tags: glkit

I am not sure if I am misunderstanding things, or I am simply tired.
Consider the two lines of code below.

```
GLKMatrix4 projection = GLKMatrix4Translate(_perspective, 0, 0, -5);
GLKMatrix4 projection = GLKMatrix4Multiply(_perspective, GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(0, 0, -5));
```

I expected them to be equivalent. But they are not. The source for GLKMatrix4Translate is:

```
static __inline__ GLKMatrix4 GLKMatrix4Translate(GLKMatrix4 matrix, float tx, float ty, float tz)
{
    GLKMatrix4 m = { matrix.m[0], matrix.m[1], matrix.m[2], matrix.m[3],
                     matrix.m[4], matrix.m[5], matrix.m[6], matrix.m[7],
                     matrix.m[8], matrix.m[9], matrix.m[10], matrix.m[11],
                     matrix.m[0] * tx + matrix.m[4] * ty + matrix.m[8] * tz + matrix.m[12],
                     matrix.m[1] * tx + matrix.m[5] * ty + matrix.m[9] * tz + matrix.m[13],
                     matrix.m[2] * tx + matrix.m[6] * ty + matrix.m[10] * tz + matrix.m[14],
                     matrix.m[15] };
    return m;
}
```

however I expected the last line to be:

```
matrix.m[3] * tx + matrix.m[7] * ty + matrix.m[11] * tz + m[15];
```

Am I correct, or in a tired fog?

Comment: Tired fog: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_%28geometry%29#Matrix_representation

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right, there must be a bug in Translate. I use the MakeTranslation+Multiply instead of the Translate function because the m[15] always remains unchanged.